# "Upon" at the very beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, writing-style

Can a sentence begin with *upon*? Or should it be changed to *on*?

For example:

> - Upon a decrease in temperature... [Is this grammatical?]
> - On a decrease in temperature... [What about this?]

Comment: Sure it's fine. A little old-fashioned though.

Comment: I'm not convinced OP's example is really "acceptable" today. As Mitch says, all such usages of *upon* are somewhat "old-fashioned". But even allowing for that, I'm not comfortable with using *upon* in contexts when it's synonymous with *whenever* (as opposed to *on the specific one-time occasion*).

Comment: From the [*American Heritage Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on): In their uses to indicate spatial relations, *on* and *upon* are often interchangeable: *It was resting on* (or *upon*) *two supports.* *We saw a finch light on* (or *upon*) *a bough.* To indicate a relation between two things, however, instead of between an action and an end point, *upon* cannot always be used: *Hand me the book on* (not *upon*) *the table. It was the only town on* (not *upon*) *the main line.* Similarly, *upon* cannot always be used in place of *on* when the relation is not spatial:

Comment: ...continued comment: *He wrote a book on* (not *upon*) *alchemy. She will be here on* (not *upon) Tuesday.* I agree with FumbleFingers, that you're probably wanting a time-related word, like *when*.

Comment: They are equivalent, and both are well-formed. As a matter of style, however, both are stiffly formal and would almost never be heard in conversation. As FumbleFingers says, these constructions should not be used to describe or prescribe routine actions. "Upon a decrease in temperature, ring the alarm" would feel right, but not "Upon a decrease in temperature proceed to step 2" would not. The most natural use is in historical narrative: "Upon hearing of Armstrong's incursion, Scrope called up his riders."

Comment: I have noticed among some of the community members a tendency to give some significance to the vote upon! Since the contrary implications of this assertion does not prove anything, I suggest you to use 'upon' at the 'very' beggining only when the sense is 'upon the occasion of' or 'when (something) occurs': "Upon disembarking from their plane ... they proceeded ..." or "Upon her return, she perused ..."! But, remember, that is a formal word and its usage can be disliked from some people! +1, anyway!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández's comment prompts me to correct myself: these constructions are reasonably natural (if somewhat formal) in present as well as historical narrative, and will accommodate repeated action in this context: "On returning from work he usually [visits/would visit] his mother."

Answer (score 1):

There are certain use cases for both, which is why we have both words.

> Upon further review I decided to go to the park.

In this example you cannot simply replace upon with on and maintain the same flow.

> On further review I decided to go to the park.

So why are they different? Upon has a more literary effect to it and sounds pretty formal in general. As FumbleFingers noted upon can indicate a one-time occasion such as

> Upon seeing the bear, I rode my horse into the sunset.

whereas "on" is used less frequently to express one-time occasions.

> On seeing the bear, I felt this sentence sounded strange.

Judging from the comments I would say it is a stylistic choice, rather than a grammatical choice.

Comment: I think it is stylistic but I have to say I prefer 'Upon...' Just saying 'On...' sounds incomplete or lazy to me. Perhaps I am just old fashioned.

Answer (score -1):

1. Upon his release from prison, he attempted to look for a good job.
2. Upon his returned, he was posted to an ill-equipped hospital in a rural  area.
3. Upon finishing his homework, he packed up and left the office.

Comment: Please add some elaboration as to why these sentences are correct (i.e. they prove a sentence can begin with *upon*).